# HBase Internal Scanner thread safety

Tags: hbase

I have a salted hbase table, and same region may have more than one salted prefix rows. For example, Region1 may have

```
00-20151010, 
00-20151011, 
01-20151010,
01-20151011,
```

Can I span multiple threads in my end point, for this region and scan each salted prefixes in parallel.

```
   forEach(String saltPrefix : salts){
      Future future = executorService.submit(myworker, region);
}
```

Here I am sharing the region across threads. Each thread will get the RegionScanner by calling

```
scanner = region.getScanner(scan);
```

My question: Is HRegion thread safe ? Can we use same region to get multiple region scanners on server side.